# Incorrect datetime value while importing in to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm facing an issue while importing a .csv file into a MySQL table.

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/script_output.csv' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE incidents columns terminated by ',' optionally 
enclosed by '"' ignore 1 lines;
```

> ```
> ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '2021-08-29T04:18:35Z'  
> for column 'incident_start' at row 1
> ```

But, I can import without an issue with `IGNORE` command.

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/script_output.csv' 
IGNORE INTO TABLE incidents columns terminated by ',' optionally 
enclosed by '"' ignore 1 lines;
```

> ```
> Query OK, 0 rows affected, 809 warnings (0.01 sec)  
> Records: 266  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 266  Warnings: 809
> ```

My requirement is to replace/update the columns in case any update on previous values in the table.

Table Structure

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| incident       | varchar(12)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| description    | varchar(300) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| status         | varchar(12)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| urgency        | varchar(7)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| service        | varchar(27)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| trigger        | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| team           | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| incident_start | datetime(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| incident_end   | datetime(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| resolved_by    | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

How we can fix the issue of Incorrect datetime while importing .csv with replace option?

Comment: The fastest method I've found for this sort of situation is to open the CSV in Excel, perform some string manipulation to convert the values to what I want (in this case, removing the `T` and `Z` characters from dates), then using the updated output as the source ...

Comment: @matigo Or importing the CSV as-is, and doing that conversion in a staging table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for this. We just need to remove the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES mode while uploading the csv file. We can use the below commands for that

```
set session sql_mode = '';
set session sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

One's it's done, we can upload the data with REPLACE

```
MariaDB [pagerduty]> LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql/pagerduty/script_output.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE temp_incidents columns terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' ignore 1 lines;
Query OK, 246 rows affected, 504 warnings (0.004 sec)
Records: 246  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 504
```

Note: The above SQL mode needs to set before uploading the file into the table everytime.